# After Home Button get pressed i got activities switch ANDROID

Tags: android

I have my first activity that switch to the second one after 3 seconds and this works fine. The problem is that if i press the Home Button during this 3 seconds, the app reopen in the second activity. Is there a simple way to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

```
    public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

            switchActivities();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed(){

        }


        public void switchActivities() {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

            }, 3000);
        }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Maybe I wasn't clear, I do not want the app to reopen once I press the home button. How can I do this?

Comment: That is expected as you are calling finish() inside switchActivities which kills the presently open activity (first one). If you want to reopen the App in 2nd activity, do not call finish().

Comment: @Ramal, This is expected behavior. When you open app from recent it open with it's current state. If you clear from recent and open again, then it work as you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you don't clear your delayed callback. You can fix it in this way:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

public void switchActivities() {
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               finish();
          }

     }, 3000);
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to cancel your Handler when you leave your first activity before the second one opens.

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Runnable nextActivityRunnable;
Handler handler;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        switchActivities();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){

    }


    public void switchActivities() {

      nextActivityRunnable = new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
            SecondActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
      };

      handler = new Handler();
      handler.postDelayed(nextActivityRunnable, 3000);
    }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    handler.removeCallbacks(nextActivityRunnable);
}

}
```